# how to configure authentification asp.net mvc using postgres in iis

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, iis

[authentification configuration in my IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D262o.jpg)
I have this code in my web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms cookieless="AutoDetect" loginUrl="~/Login/Index" />
</authentication>
```

I have no database configured because I want to use postgres.
but when I run my website I have this error :

> L'utilisation d'une section inscrite comme
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' au-delà du niveau d'application
>   est une erreur. Cette erreur peut provenir d'un répertoire virtuel non
>   configuré en tant qu'application dans IIS.